# working out Vout for an Opamp circuit that has a common base npn transistor instead of a resistor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier

[image: Opamp with Transitor circuit]

Im not able to figure this out I have Vin, R1 and saturation current of the transistor.
Do I need to work out resistance of the transistor first or follow a different method I am very lost with this one.

[image: transistor equation]

I have found this equation but I do not have a load resistor so am unsure of what to do.

Comment: In this configuration, the transistor act just like any ordinary diode.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_amplifier

Answer (score 1):

You know the voltage at pin 2 is 0V so you can can calculate the current through R1 (assuming the op-amp is in balance and is stable).

So you also know the collector current of Q1, and the base voltage. As G36 indicates you can ignore the base current and treat the transistor as an (ideal) diode with \$\eta\$ = 1.

You will notice that less-than-useful things will happen if Vin < 0V.

Comment: so I followed this and the comment left above to first work out Ic= 15/10K = 1.5mA. Next was Vt = kT/q to get the thermal voltage 0.02613V. then finally Vout = -Vt*ln(Vin/Iso*R1) which got me -0.3295V. Does that sound correct?